# Is normal Traefik generates an `TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT` for some hours?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, traefik

I'm using Kubernetes in Google Cloud Platform.
I configured a cluster with Traefik with SSL and Lets Encrypt, it works well, then I changed a little setting in `[acme]` and I start receiving this error after `kubectl apply -f .`: `TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT`.

[image]

I already rollback the file settings, but I continue to receive this error (with previous configurations).

It's normal?

I just need to wait because Letsencrypt need time? For how long time?

Thanks.